# Adding null values to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, highcharts

I have a pandas dataframe that is used to create a JSON which in turn is used to display a highcharts chart.

Pandas dataframe:

```
Date        colA    colB
12-Sep-14   20      40
13-Sep-14   50      10
14-Sep-14   12      -20
15-Sep-14   74      43
```

Is there a way to change some of the colA and colB values to null. The reason for this is that I ultimately need a JSON that looks something like this:

```
[
    [12-Sep-14, 20, 40],
    [13-Sep-14, null, null],
    [14-Sep-14, 12, -20],
    [15-Sep-14, 74, 43]
]
```

The reason for this is that I require a highcharts chart where certain plot points are blank. To do this, you specify the date followed by null.

So I need to somehow update certain values in the pandas dataframe so that once I convert it to a JSON using .to_json() then the json will contain the specified null values as per the example above.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: this removes the "" around null: df.to_json(orient='values').replace("\"","")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
import pandas as pd
# Read in data frame from clipboard
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df = df.replace(df.iloc[1][1:],'null')

        Date  colA  colB
0  12-Sep-14    20    40
1  13-Sep-14  null  null
2  14-Sep-14    12   -20
3  15-Sep-14    74    43
```

Here, df.iloc[1] gives access to row 1

Finally,

```
df.to_json(orient='values').replace("\"","")
```

gives json without the ""

```
[[12-Sep-14,20,40],[13-Sep-14,null,null],[14-Sep-14,12,-20],[15-Sep-14,74,43]]
```

Comment: Remove double quotes from a JSON string??? This is a VERY limited solution

Answer (score 10):

Try using `NaN` which is the Pandas missing value:

```
from numpy import nan 

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.colA.iloc[1] = NaN
```

instead of `NaN` you could also use `None`. Note that neither of these terms are entered with quotes.

Then you can use `to_json()` to get your output:

```
df.to_json()
'{"Date":{"0":"12-Sep-14","1":"13-Sep-14","2":"14-Sep-14","3":"15-Sep-14"},"colA":{"0":20.0,"1":null,"2":12.0,"3":74.0},"colB":{"0":40,"1":10,"2":-20,"3":43}}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but NaN, None or '' dont work. NameError: name 'NaN' is not defined. The json is created using df.to_json(orient='values'). The json is created correctly. The issue is with trying to insert null's. The resulting json needs to look exactly like the example, ie: the word null with no quotation marks. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: If you have NaN in a Pandas dataframe and you call the to_json() method it creates exactly what you are saying you want. I'll update the example above to illustrate. What code is giving you the "NameError" error?

Comment: This won't work unless you specify `from numpy import nan`. Reason is that `nan` doesn't come from pandas, but from numpy.

Comment: Thanks, had simlar issue, None helped

Answer (score 4):

Code as below:

```
import numpy as np

# create null/NaN value with np.nan
df.loc[1, colA:colB] = np.nan
```

Here's the explanation:

1. locate the entities that need to be replaced: `df.loc[1, colA:colB]` means selecting row 1 and columns from colA to colB;
2. assign the NaN value `np.nan` to the specific location.

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation of how this works? Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).