# Adding Null values to a pandas dataframe using a if-elif statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function, if-statement

I've tried the following site for the answer to no success:

[Adding null values to a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805445/adding-null-values-to-a-pandas-dataframe)

I need to add null values through a python function.

```
from numpy import nan

def f(row):
    if row['model'] == 'C5' and row['x'] <= 600:
        val = 600
    elif row['model'] == 'C5' and row['x'] > 600 and row['score'] <= 675:
        val = 675
    elif row['model'] == 'C5' and row['x'] > 675 and row['score'] <= 710:
        val = 710
    elif row['model'] == 'C5' and row['x'] > 710 and row['score'] <= 745:
        val = 745 
    elif row['CREDIT_MODEL_CODE'] == 'C5' and row['x'] > 745:
        val = 999
    elif row['model'] == 'C5' and row['x'] == 'X': 
        val = 3
    elif row['model'] == 'C5' and row['x'] == 'T': 
        val = 2
    elif row['model'] == "":
        val = 1
    return val

df['column'] = df.apply(f, axis = 1)
```

I've also tried using `NaN` and `Null` in place of `""`.  Anyone know how I can add null values based on other conditions using an if-elif statement?

I keep getting the following error:

> ```
>  48 
>  49     else:
> ```
>
> ---> 50         val == ""
>        51 
>        52     return val
>
> UnboundLocalError: ("local variable 'val' referenced before
>   assignment", 'occurred at index 60')

Comment: Look at pd.cut~

Comment: why not just `else:`

Comment: Hi @MaartenFabré.  This still throws an error as it's expecting `val` to have a value.